# serve static files of a web app having nginx as a proxy

Tags: nginx, python, django, gunicorn

I am trying to use nginx as a proxy for a web app (django running on gunicorn)

```
server  {

    listen                      80;
    server_name                 registry.blabla;

    error_log                   /var/log/nginx/registry.blabla.error.log;
    access_log                  /var/log/nginx/registry.blabla.access.log;

    location /favicon.ico   { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static        { 
    root            /home/xxx/registry;
    }
#    location /         {
#   try_files       $uri $uri/ @backend;
#    }
    location /          {
        proxy_pass              http://blabla:8989/registryadmin/;

        proxy_redirect          off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        client_max_body_size    10m;
        client_body_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_connect_timeout   90;
        proxy_send_timeout      90;
        proxy_read_timeout      90;
        proxy_buffers           32 4k;

    }

}
```

The proxy merely works. What I mean is that proxying the web app works.
BUT, the static files of the web app are not served.

Looking at the logs:

```
==> /var/log/nginx/registry.blabla.error.log <==
2017/05/27 20:31:18 [error] 4262#0: *3 open() "/home/xxx/registry/static/admin/css/base.css" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 172.31.135.23, server: registry.blabla, request: "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1", host: "registry.blabla", referrer: "http://registry.blabla/"

==> /var/log/nginx/registry.blabla.access.log <==
172.31.135.23 - - [27/May/2017:20:31:18 +0200] "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1" 403 169 "http://registry.blabla/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/603.2.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.5"

==> /var/log/nginx/registry.blabla.error.log <==
2017/05/27 20:31:18 [error] 4262#0: *4 open() "/home/xxx/registry/static/admin/css/dashboard.css" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 172.31.135.23, server: registry.blabla, request: "GET /static/admin/css/dashboard.css HTTP/1.1", host: "registry.blabla", referrer: "http://registry.blabla/"

==> /var/log/nginx/registry.blabla.access.log <==
172.31.135.23 - - [27/May/2017:20:31:18 +0200] "GET /static/admin/css/dashboard.css HTTP/1.1" 403 169 "http://registry.blabla/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/603.2.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.1.1 Safari/603.2.5"
```

Could you please advise on how-to possibly resolve this ?

EDIT:

adding the selinux context outputs requests in the comments:

```
# ls -ldZ /home
drwxr-xr-x. root root system_u:object_r:home_root_t:s0 /home
# ls -ldZ /home/app
drwx------. app app unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 /home/app
# ls -ldZ /home/app/registry
drwxrwxr-x. app app unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 /home/app/registry
```

Comment: nginx is unable to access your static files due to incorrect permissions. Fix permissions for your static files.

Comment: @AlexD permissions are set as `775` do you mean anything different maybe ?

Comment: Check permissions for all sub-directory tree where your static files are placed. Each sub-directory needs to have read and execute permissions for nginx user.

Comment: thanks! it is set like that with the `-R` option. but still..

Comment: Do you have SELinux enabled?

Comment: in `permissive` state and the `audit.log` shows no errors

Comment: Please show output for `ls -ldZ /home`, `ls -ldZ /home/xxx` and so on up to 'css' sub-dir

Comment: thanks @AlexD for looking into it. please see edit  above i pasted the requested outputs

Answer (score 2):

Your '/home/app' directory has '700' permissions which restricts access to user 'app' only. You need to change it to allow access for a user ID which 'nginx' process uses.

Comment: thanks @AlexD but please note that the nginx proxy is on a different server. I believe that the case is like the one described here https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/serving-static-content/ and the `@backend` location

Comment: It is irrelevant if nginx is on a different server. If you want it to serve static content out of a directory it must have permissions on that directory.

Comment: @NikosSkalis you configured your nginx to serve static files from its local file system, so these static files should be present on this local file system, otherwise you need to remove 'location /static' and configure your remote gunicorn to serve static files on its own, which will be quite suboptimal

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a trailing slash to /static? You're also not telling nginx what its allowed to serve by default from static so it assumes no access.

```
location /static/ {
    root    /home/xxx/registry;
    try_files    $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

Comment: thanks @NotoriousPyro i tried that, unfortunately static files are not loaded still, the error messages though have changed, from `open` to `stat`

Comment: `2017/05/28 09:57:45 [error] 4262#0: *14 open() "/home/app/registry/static/admin/css/dashboard.css" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 172.31.135.25, server: registry.blabla, request: "GET /static/admin/css/dashboard.css HTTP/1.1", host: "registry.blabla", referrer: "http://registry.blabla/"`

Comment: `2017/05/28 14:40:09 [crit] 5966#0: *1 stat() "/home/app/registry/static/admin/css/base.css" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 172.31.135.25, server: registry.blabla, request: "GET /static/admin/css/base.css HTTP/1.1", host: "registry.blabla", referrer: "http://registry.blabla/"`

Comment: In that case then, your problem lies with the permissions on /home/app. What 'user' and 'group' is nginx running at? Because only 'app' user can access that location because of the permissions on /home/app it can never reach /home/app/registry or /home/app/registry/static

Comment: i have set it like that `chmod 705 /home/app` and the subdirectories permissions are `755`. but no luck

Comment: 'You're also not telling nginx what its allowed to serve by default ' @NotoriousPyro could you please enlighten me please a bit more what you mean with this one ?